# Does SEO value pass through canonical links pointing to another domain?

Tags: seo, pagerank, canonical-url

I have a relatively new price aggregation website (online for about one month). Part of it was also adapted (custom header/footer) and included into an older site, on a different domain, which already has a Google PageRank,  and domain authority.

In order to prevent duplicate content and to promote the main website, the integration contains canonical-url links on the old website pointing to the respective website pages on the new domain.

From a SEO point of view will any rank juice be passed from the older website and domain (which contains the integration) to the new one through the canonical links?
Or is it better to just add "dofollow" links from the integration to the main website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, pagerank flow from a cross-domain canonical link would be similar to a 301 redirect.

However, for the canonical link to work effectively be sure that these pages are intended to be the exact same - for partial content it is much better to use the blockquote. See my answer to this question:
[Should I use a canonical tag when only 50% of the content is duplicated?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76872/should-i-use-a-canonical-tag-when-only-50-of-the-content-is-duplicated/76873#76873)

In regards to the business decision, it would depend on how much organic traffic you intend to get from these canonicalised pages.

If the existing pages where the content garners little traffic, the decision to use canonical links is easy. *But* if the old website garners good to decent traffic you may see a sharp fall off before the equivalent pages on the new website.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the old website has a very targeted audience (specialists) and I can say that the traffic is 5 to 10 times lower than on the new website. BUT it does have a pageRank 3, while the new site does not yet have any pageRank. Your answer with the blockquote is very interesting, I will keep it in mind for my future optimizations.